# RPi web cam interface default directory for recorded videos

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to recover the videos I recorded but:

My raspberry pi suddenly won't boot and hangs at

```
[ OK ] Reached target System Time Synchronized
```

My last task was recording several videos using the RPi web cam interface from
[here.](https://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface)

I turned off the Pi by just unplugging the power after I finished recording videos then right after I power it on the problem started to happen.

The documentation says the default video_path is

```
 /var/www/html/media/vi_%v_%Y%M%D_%h%m%s.mp4
```

I have access to the "/var" directory using ext2explore software but there is no sign of videos.

[image]

Comment: check whatever directory you were in when you recorded the video, and if possible edit your question to include the command you used to record them. Have you tried using the search/find function of the machine you are using?

Comment: Yeah I did look for files with size > 1 MB (videos are as high as +/- 200 MB) but no videos were found, the record was done using the web interface  (I just pressed the record button.) I have been using the interface for a while and it was fine until I recorded 16 times in a row, shut it off, and on then stuck at boot. Btw, I am using ext2explore (Windows) to recover files by mounting the sd card of the RPi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) did the trick. I was able to recover the videos but the file names are not the same.